# I am calling userDao.findById(Integer i) and is giving java.lang.NullPointerException i am giving the exact id that is in db

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here is my code:

```
public class Test_JPA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserDao uDao = new UserDaoImplement();
        User u = uDao.findById(4);
        System.out.println(u.getName());
    }

}
```

At my `UserDaoImplement();`

```
@Stateless
public class UserDaoImplement implements UserDao{

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserDaoImplement.class);
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
public User findById(Integer id) {
    log.debug("getting User instance with id: " + id);
    try {
        User instance = entityManager.find(User.class, id);
        log.debug("get successful");
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

and here is my persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="WebApp" 
transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"
>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.model.Profile</class>
        <class>com.model.User</class>
<properties>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />-->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <!--  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
        -->
        <!-- per hibernate 4.3 -->
    <!--    <property name="hibernate.currrent_session_context_class" value="org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocal‌​SessionContext"/>
    -->
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Please at the `User` entity.

Comment: Also, please add full stacktrace.

Comment: Feb 15, 2015 6:28:34 PM com.dao.impl.UserDaoImplement findById
SEVERE: get failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.dao.impl.UserDaoImplement.findById(UserDaoImplement.java:85)
 at com.test_jpa.Test_JPA.main(Test_JPA.java:14)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.dao.impl.UserDaoImplement.findById(UserDaoImplement.java:85)
 at com.test_jpa.Test_JPA.main(Test_JPA.java:14)

Comment: so you get an NPE, so what is null? It's the EntityManager? so why is it null? so make it not be null.

Comment: actually i thought that @PersistanceContext didnt need spring modules cuz i am new to JPA and hibernate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats at line 85 in UserDaoImplement.java. I am willing to bet its the entitymanager. You seem to have done `UserDao uDao = new UserDaoImplement();` this i your test case. How do you expect the `private EntityManager entityManager;` to populate in your `uDao` instance inside your test case?

Comment: User instance = entityManager.find(User.class, id);
this is in line 85.i am just giving the id

Comment: you are using the annotation `@PersistenceContext` for entitymanager. Someone has to read that annotation and inject the PersistenceContext inside your entitymanager variable. Normally Spring or a dependency injection framework does that. But when you do `new UserDaoImplement()` who is taking care of injecting the PersistenceContext ? Answer is no one. And that is why you are getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you :) very much , so without spring i just have to create EntityManagerFactory with persistance unit ?

Comment: No. Read about 'integration testing' with Spring. You can inject your spring context inside your test cases and then use the spring beans as it is without any `new` calls.

Answer (score 0):

sorry forgot User Entity

@Entity
@Table
public class User
{

```
private Integer id;
private Profile profile;
private String name;
private String email;
private String username;
private String password;

public User() {
}

public User(Profile profile, String name, String email, String username,
        String password) {
    this.profile = profile;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
public Profile getProfile() {
    return this.profile;
}

public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}

@Column(name = "name", length = 45)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "email", length = 45)
public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Column(name = "username", length = 20)
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "password", length = 20)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}